# Where can I find an unabridged English translation of Harivamsa?

Tags: resource, harivamsa

I know about the KM Ganguli translation of Mahabharata. Did he also translate Harivamsa Parva? If so, where can I find his (or any other) English translation?

Comment: M. N. Dutt's translation is available on [Google Books](https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=M_lKAQAAMAAJ&pg=GBS.PP7). Also, see [Is the Harivamsha a canonical text as part of the Mahabharatha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/30417/is-the-harivamsha-a-canonical-text-as-part-of-the-mahabharatha)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The translations by following translators are available:

- [Hanumath Rao](http://mahabharata-resources.org/harivamsa/harivamsa-cs-index.html)
- [MN Dutt](https://archive.org/details/AProseEnglishTranslationOfHarivamsh)
- [B. Debroy.](https://archive.org/details/TheMahabharata_201707)
- [Dr. Narendra Sharma](https://archive.org/details/TheMahabharataVol.2TheHarivamsa_201807)

Comment: The link you posted of MN Dutt translation is not available. Also, said KN Ganguli translated Harivamsa?

Comment: Also are both of these translations unabridged?

Comment: @RishX yes they are unabridged.

Comment: ok. Still MN Dutt translation is not working. The file is not there.

Comment: @RishX I will fix the problem soon

Comment: "Dr. Narendra Sharma" - this seems to be the one who uploaded the content on Archive instead of the author